# VB.NET comparison of an array with filename values from a Outlook mail item attachment list matches only once when more should happen

Tags: vb.net, outlook

I am writing an Outlook Email VB.NET program that should parse an email, place it into a form for modification of individual fields, and then save the mail and any attachments, as modified, into a directory on the file system.

I need to read values into an array from a multi-line textbox containing attachments. Then I compare them to the values in the complete list of file names in the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application.MailItem.Attachment.FileName` values. *I can only match each filename once though.*  Only the first value in the text box will match. It doesn't matter what the value is, as long as it is in the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application.MailItem.Attachment.FileName` values, it matches that and nothing else.

In addition to the code I am posting, I have tried other methods like "contains" and "is" in place of the comparisons, but nothing changes except the "Is" won't match even the first time.  The code has gone through many modifications even though other methods still produced the same result.

Here is the relevant code:

```
    ' Dim mailAttachments As Outlook.Attachments = Mail.Attachments
    ListBoxAttachmentArray = SaveAttachment_List.Split(Environment.NewLine)
    If ListBoxAttachmentArray.Length > 0 Then
        For i As Integer = 0 To ListBoxAttachmentArray.Length - 2
            StatusBox.Text += Environment.NewLine & "A:" & ListBoxAttachmentArray(i)
            For j As Integer = 1 To mailAttachments.Count
                ' currentAttachment = mailAttachments.Item(j)
                StatusBox.Text += Environment.NewLine + ListBoxAttachmentArray(i)
                StatusBox.Text += " : " & mailAttachments.Item(j).FileName
                StatusBox.Text += Environment.NewLine + " i: " + i.ToString + " j: " + j.ToString
                If mailAttachments.Item(j).FileName = ListBoxAttachmentArray(i) Then
                    StatusBox.Text += Environment.NewLine & "MadeIt: " & mailAttachments.Item(j).FileName
                    'mailAttachments.Item(j).Save(UsedDir & mailAttachments.Item(j).FileName, True)
                End If
            Next
        Next
    End If
```

Here is a list of three files that are in my text box, as an example:

```
image001.jpg
Mold RFQ 07162020 IP Driver Accent - Chinstrap.xlsx
BEV-15046A62-A_REV_17.zip
```

and here is the status text box I am using to trace the above code:

```
A:image001.jpg
image001.jpg : image001.jpg
 i: 0 j: 1
MadeIt: image001.jpg
image001.jpg : Mold RFQ 07162020 IP Driver Accent - Chinstrap.xlsx
 i: 0 j: 2
image001.jpg : BEV-15046A62-A_REV_17.zip
 i: 0 j: 3
A: Mold RFQ 07162020 IP Driver Accent - Chinstrap.xlsx
Mold RFQ 07162020 IP Driver Accent - Chinstrap.xlsx : image001.jpg
 i: 1 j: 1
Mold RFQ 07162020 IP Driver Accent - Chinstrap.xlsx : Mold RFQ 07162020 IP DriverAccent - Chinstrap.xlsx
 i: 1 j: 2
Mold RFQ 07162020 IP Driver Accent - Chinstrap.xlsx : BEV-15046A62-A_REV_17.zip
 i: 1 j: 3
A: BEV-15046A62-A_REV_17.zip
BEV-15046A62-A_REV_17.zip : image001.jpg
 i: 2 j: 1
BEV-15046A62-A_REV_17.zip : Mold RFQ 07162020 IP Driver Accent - Chinstrap.xlsx
i: 2 j: 2
BEV-15046A62-A_REV_17.zip : BEV-15046A62-A_REV_17.zip
 i: 2 j: 3
```

Notice the "Made it" in the output.  This should happen three times, but only the first time the loops match causes it to happen.

How can I make this match each time?

Comment: Try applying `.Trim()` to the values before comparison .BTW, `For i As Integer = 0 To ListBoxAttachmentArray.Length - 2` should be `For i As Integer = 0 To ListBoxAttachmentArray.Length - 1`.

Comment: preciousbetine, Thank you so VERY MUCH.  Your answer with the .Trim() method solved this!  And, so quickly you replied!  I tried Trim, but I put the values inside the parenthesis instead of placing it at the end of the values.  As for the -2 V -1, my code needs the -2.  I am not entirely sure why this is, but I assure you it works only with the -2.  I will try to mark this correct (first post...)

Comment: What is this code actually doing? You have 3 items in your textbox and 3 attachments in your email; this entire code is unnecessary - just save the 3 attachments

Comment: The text box is editable.  Some files will not be saved, so the code does a match.  This may be ignorance, but I use the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application.MailItem.Attachment.SaveAsFile() method to actually save the attachments, but only on those that the end user keeps in the text box.  In the case in the example, there is a 100% match.  Perhaps in the question I should have done a partial list for your pleasure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should trim the string values before comparing them to get accurate results.

```
If mailAttachments.Item(j).FileName.Trim() = ListBoxAttachmentArray(i).Trim() Then
    StatusBox.Text += Environment.NewLine & "MadeIt: " & mailAttachments.Item(j).FileName
   'mailAttachments.Item(j).Save(UsedDir & mailAttachments.Item(j).FileName, True)
End If
```